# MySQL WHERE multiple columns LIKE '%$sq%' returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i'm making a social network CMS from the ground up with php and MySQL

I need the search to work by searching through the user's username, display name and email to return results from any of the above

```
<?php require('core.common.php');
//Search page php
$sq    = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q'], ENT_QUOTES);

$search = $db->prepare("SELECT username, disp_name, profilepic 
FROM users WHERE username OR disp_name OR email LIKE '%sq%';"); 
$search->execute();
$viewsearch = $search->fetchAll();
```

I've tried this which works but only on one column at a time:

```
$search = $db->prepare("SELECT username, disp_name, profilepic
    FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$sq%';");
```

I've already tried...

```
"SELECT username, disp_name, profilepic FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%sq%'OR disp_name LIKE '%sq%'OR email LIKE '%sq%' ORDER BY username;"
```

And

```
"SELECT username, disp_name, profilepic FROM users WHERE ((username LIKE '%sq%') OR (disp_name LIKE '%sq%') OR (email LIKE '%sq%'));"
```

Along with a couple variants of the above and still no hope.

Comment: Each OR condition should have a value it is tested against. Where A like X OR B like Y OR C like Z

Comment: does the db have to be using a certain storage engine, mine is InnoDB

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT username, disp_name, profilepic 
FROM users 
WHERE username LIKE '%sq%'
OR disp_name LIKE '%sq%'
OR email LIKE '%sq%'
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work, it just returns
Array
(
)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
SELECT username, disp_name, profilepic 
FROM users 
WHERE username LIKE '%sq%'
    OR disp_name LIKE '%sq%'
    OR email LIKE '%sq%';
```

Comment: http://wisp-r.com/search.php?q=mow

Comment: Are you sure you have data that should match this query?

Comment: my main testing account is mowglixx